# Foxbase to postrgresql data transfer. (dbf files reader)

Tags: sql, database, transfer, dbf

I rewrite a program based on the old Foxbase database consisting of files .dbf. I need a tool that would read these files, and helped in the transfer of data to PostgreSQL. You know maybe some of this type of tool?

Comment: You could write one fairly easily with this information http://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html

Comment: @HughJones It isn't as clear-cut as you'd hope. There are plenty of weird edge cases depending on which program generated the files. For instance, some flavors of DBF use binary coded decimals for numeric fields and memo file offsets where others use ints. There's also a nasty mix of big and little endian numbers.

Answer (score 2):

pgdbf.sourceforge.net - has worked for all the DBF I've fed it. Quoting the site description:

> PgDBF is a program for converting XBase databases - particularly
>   FoxPro tables with memo files - into a format that PostgreSQL can
>   directly import. It's a compact C project with no dependencies other
>   than standard Unix libraries.

If you are looking for something to run on Windows, and this doesn't compile directly, you could use cygwin (www.cygwin.com) to build and run pgdbf.

Comment: Does it actually work to run it under Cygwin? I don't know why it wouldn't, but it'd be cool if it does! (I wrote PgDBF.)

Answer (score 1):

As part of the migration path you could use [Python](http://python.org) and [my dbf module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf).  A very simple script to convert the dbf files to csv would be:

```
import sys
import dbf
dbf.export(sys.argv[1])
```

which will create a `.csv` file of the same name as the dbf file.  If you put that code into a script named `dbf2csv.py` you could then call it as

```
python dbf2csv.py dbfname
```

Hopefully there are some handy tools to get the csv file into PostgreSQL.

Comment: This now causes an error  
```File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbf/utils.py", line 78, in export
    table = source_table(table_or_records[0])
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbf/utils.py", line 365, in source_table
    table = thingie._meta.table()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'```